I need to turn a full sheet
I'm needing to turn a whole sheet.
try using \usepackage{lscape}, \begin{landscape}, \end{landscape}.
But this actually turns the image, and not the sheet. I need to rotate the entire sheet from passing vertical to horizontal. How can i do?

lscape (you may prefer pdflscape) is unrelated to images, it rotates the whole page while keeping the page head and foot in the original portrait orientation.

What exactly do you need?

Do you want only the lines of text within the typeblock (not within the headers, not within the footers, not within the margin-notes) of a page/sheet to be justified vertically instead of horizontally? (This is what, despite the package's name the package lscape is for.)
Do you want a page of the document to be rotated by 90 degree when the pdf-viewer displays it?
Do you want to recalculate the type area for a page so that instead of portrait it is landscape or instead of landscape it is portrait?

The package pdflscape is used to combine 1 and 2 so that when looking at pages where lines of text in the type block are justified vertically you don't need to tilt your head to the left/to right.
Perhaps one of the approaches exhibited in the following does the trick for you:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{typearea}  % to change page margins
\usepackage{lipsum}    % For dummy text; you can remove this in your actual document
\usepackage{pdflscape} % For landscape pages
\usepackage{showframe} % To display page borders
\usepackage{iftex}     % Detect TeX engine in use

\newcommand\savetextheight{}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \storeareas\Standardlayout
  \newcommand\SavedStandardTextwidth{}%
  \newcommand\SavedStandardTextheight{}%
  \xdef\SavedStandardTextwidth{\number\textwidth\space sp}%
  \xdef\SavedStandardTextheight{\number\textheight\space sp}%
}%
\BeforeRestoreareas{\clearpage}%

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\section{Non-rotated stuff}
\marginpar{\raggedright margin note margin note}%
\lipsum[1-4]

\edef\savetextheight{\number\textheight\space sp\relax}%
\begin{landscape}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\ShowFramePicture{%
  \begingroup
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %  \textheight is modified within the landscape-environment because the box holding the text
    %  is rotated. But the frames around the text are drawn on the sheet of paper, which during
    %  typesetting is not rotated (, although pdflscape tells pdf-viewers to display it rotated).
    %  Thus modification of \textheight is to be undone while drawing the frames:
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \textheight=\savetextheight
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \ShowFrameColor\linethickness{\ShowFrameLinethickness}%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \framebox(\paperwidth,\paperheight){}}%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \framebox(\textwidth,\textheight){}}%
    \AtTextUpperLeft{%
      \put(0,\headsep){%
        \framebox(\textwidth,\headheight){}}}%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \put(0,-\footskip){%
        \line(1,0){\textwidth}}}%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \SF@tempdima=\textwidth\advance\SF@tempdima\marginparsep
      \if@twoside
        \ifodd\c@page\else
          \if@mparswitch
            \SF@tempdima=-\marginparsep\advance\SF@tempdima-\marginparwidth
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
      \put(\SF@tempdima,0)%
        {\framebox(\marginparwidth,\textheight){}}%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\section[typeblock vertically, page rotated]{Type block's text lines justified vertically, page displayed by pdf-viewer rotated by 90 degrees}
%\marginpar{\raggedright margin note margin note}% \marginpar is broken here
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{landscape}%

\section{Non-rotated stuff}
\marginpar{\raggedright margin note margin note}%
\lipsum[1-4]

\clearpage
\begingroup
\ifxetex
  \special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate 90>>}%
\else
  \pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}%
\fi
\section{Entire page displayed rotated by 90 degrees}
\marginpar{\raggedright margin note margin note}%
\lipsum[1-4]
\clearpage
\endgroup

\section{Non-rotated stuff}
\marginpar{\raggedright margin note margin note}%
\lipsum[1-4]

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,pagesize}\recalctypearea
\areaset{\SavedStandardTextheight}{\SavedStandardTextwidth}%
\section{Type area recalculated for landscape}
\marginpar{\raggedright margin note margin note}%
\lipsum[1-4]
\Standardlayout

\section{Non-rotated stuff}
\marginpar{\raggedright margin note margin note}%
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}


